# How to reshape timestamp in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have an imported cell in Google Sheets with the following string representing a time/date format:

```
2019-03-30T14:39:07-03:00
```

What would be the correct `REGEXTRACT` or `DATEVALUE` formula solution so that it will result in a valid Google Sheets date&time format?

The `-03:00` at the end of the string can be ignored.

---

```
2019-03-30T14:39:07-03:00
```

should result in

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**all you need is:**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1, 19), "T", " ")
```

[image: 0]

---

**for the whole column:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1:A, 19), "T", " "))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXREPLACE` and use this regex,

```
.*?(\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}).(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}).*
```

And replace it with `$1 $2`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wIpoeq/2)**

I've tested and it works well in Google sheets.

Just use this,

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ".*?(\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}).(\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2}).*", "$1 $2")
```

And replace in the cell you want to get your desired value.

Here is a screenshot showing the google sheets demo,

[image]

As you can see in the samples, this regex will find the date, no matter the date is surrounded by any optional text. In each of the case, you will have your desired date extract in the next column or any column you want.

Comment: Your solution works very well and is robust, however for my case @5632629 provided a very simple way to solve it also with SUBSTITUTE

Comment: @Frank: Sure buddy, use the one that suits best to your needs :)